# ¿Por qué el IDE me sugiere que reemplace + con append en StringBuilder de Java?

Tags: java, buenas-prácticas

Si uso un `StringBuilder` en Java, en ocasiones, por pereza, intento unir dos valores en un mismo `append`:

```
    //Agregamos datos al sb
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(strTiempo);
            sb.append(strSemana);
            sb.append(strSalterio);
            sb.append(sMensaje+SEPARADOR); //aquí uso +
            //...
```

¿Por qué el IDE me sugiere:

> Replace `+` with `StringBuilder.append`

Comment: Con independencia de cual sea el motivo real, es más legible la forma que te indica el IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La expresión

```
String s =
   a + b + c + d + e;
```

Te hace:

- Crea String temp1 = a + b;
- Crea String temp2 = temp1 + c;
- Crea String temp3 = temp2 + d;
- Crea String s = temp3 + e;

4 objetos creados, 1 útil, 3 a eliminar por el *garbage collection*<sup>1</sup>.

Por comparación, con *StringBuilder* creas un único objeto extra con el que realizas todas las operaciones<sup>2</sup>. En tu caso además, el `StringBuilder` ya está creado y basta con llamar al método; es "crear uno (o varios) objetos innecesarios" o "llamar a un método".

Si es algo que utilices una vez en tu aplicación no hay problema en usar `+`, pero si es un código que se ejecute constantemente la penalización de rendimiento es importante.

Y antes de que alguien comente, recuerdo que `String` es immutable así que cada invocación a `String.concat` también crea un nuevo objeto, siendo así equivalente (en cuanto a rendimiento) a `+`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Recuerdo que en algún momento me comentaron que, además, la JVM creaba internamente `StringBuilder` para hacer las concatenaciones con `+`, con lo cual la ineficiencia aún es mayor. Pero no estoy seguro si se referían a detalles de implementación de una JVM o viene dado por las especificaciones.

<sup>2</sup>`StringBuilder` tendrá internamente un buffer con la cadena y estoy seguro de que, si haces `String`s muy grandes, en algún momento, tendrá que redimiensionarlo. Pero incluso aunque con cada concatenación hubiera un redimensionamiento (que sería un caso muy excepcional) no sería peor que usar `+`.

Answer (score 2):

El compilador suele optimizar el código del append del StringBuilder, por lo que en debug y si se ejecuta dicho código muchas veces será *insignificantemente más rápido*, así que no hay problema en que utilices el código como has indicado. 
Así todo te recuerdo **cuando usar** cada tipo de String:

- Si el texto no va a cambiar, utilizar String.
- Si va a cambiar, y la
  aplicación va a tener un solo hilo de ejecución, utilizar StringBuilder.
- Si el texto cambia durante la ejecución, y la
  aplicación que accede a él es multi-thread, utilizaremos
  StringBuffer.

Comment: Hola, ¿tienes la fuente de dicha información?

Comment: Solo hay que buscar compilator append para encontrar referencias a lo que comento: http://javamoods.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/optimization-dont-do-it-compiler-will.html , http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html

Comment: Muchas GRACIAS!